# Clear setTimeout()

Tags: javascript

I have a list of videos, if the user clicks on one video then clicks on a second video before the first one has finished, the timer keeps going and second video changes when it shouldn't. I have tried using clearTimeout to stop the first video timer but it isn't doing anything.

```
  var last_div = 0;
  function getVid(div_num, vid_length, count, id)
  {
  clearTimeout(timer1)
  time_limit = vid_length * 1000 + 4000;  //plus 4000 is to account for the lagging of the youtube video loading

    if(last_div == 0)
    {
      last_div = div_num;
      document.getElementById("vid_div" + div_num).style.background="#DCE4EB";
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById("vid_div" + last_div).style.background="";
      last_div = div_num;
      document.getElementById("vid_div" + div_num).style.background="#DCE4EB";
    }

    player.loadVideoById(id);
    player.setVolume(20);

    if(div_num != count)
    {
    div_num++;

      var timer1 = setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("vid_div" + div_num).onclick();
      },
      time_limit);
    }
    else
    {
      setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("vid_div" + div_num).style.background="";
      },
      time_limit);
    }
  }
```

Comment: `clearTimeout()` requires a reference to the id of the timeout. I see you stored one of the calls in `timer1` but not the other one... why?

Comment: That was just a mistake.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yeah, as George has shown, the reference to the timeout needs to be outside the function, since it loses the reference the next time it's called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to:

```
 var last_div = 0,timer1;
  function getVid(div_num, vid_length, count, id)
  {
  clearTimeout(timer1)
  time_limit = vid_length * 1000 + 4000;  //plus 4000 is to account for the lagging of the youtube video loading

    if(last_div == 0)
    {
      last_div = div_num;
      document.getElementById("vid_div" + div_num).style.background="#DCE4EB";
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById("vid_div" + last_div).style.background="";
      last_div = div_num;
      document.getElementById("vid_div" + div_num).style.background="#DCE4EB";
    }

    player.loadVideoById(id);
    player.setVolume(20);

    if(div_num != count)
    {
    div_num++;

      timer1 = setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("vid_div" + div_num).onclick();
      },
      time_limit);
    }
    else
    {
      timer1 = setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("vid_div" + div_num).style.background="";
      },
      time_limit);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`var timer1` is a local variable. That is one of your problems. The other problem is the other setTimeout does not have a variable.